# Linux shell $() vs ``

Tags: linux, shell

To assign the result of some command to some variable one can find the following shell code :

```
linesToProcess=$(get_lines some_string_to_case)
```

As for me it looks the same to

```
linesToProcess=`get_lines some_string_to_case`
```

Do these lines mean the same? Are they both portable?